# Christoph Gohlke Naming Convention for Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages

Tags: python, naming-conventions, python-wheel

What is the naming convention used for the Python wheels at 
[Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)?

For example, for scipy here are two of names of wheels on the page:

scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl

scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

What does 'none' indicate?

What's the difference between win32 and win_amd64?

Does it matter if I'm using the x86 or x86-64 version of Python (ref [Python 2.7.11](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/))?

Answer (score 6):

Actually that's the [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/) tool "naming convention". Sincerely I'm not sure what "none" indicates, but yes, your Python version matters. If you're using the 32-bit interpreter, then go ahead with the `win32` option (under Windows, of course). Otherwise download the `win_amd64` version for 64-bit distributions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Following the wheel link in this answer, led me to [wheel file naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/).  On this page look for the section **File Format** with subsection **File Naming Convention**.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:** it's the wheel naming convention and `none` means it's pure python.

I've taken the extra step to follow answer/comments.

The `none` in this case is probably the ABI tag. From [PEP 425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/):

> The ABI tag indicates which Python ABI is required by any included
>   extension modules. For implementation-specific ABIs, the
>   implementation is abbreviated in the same way as the Python Tag, e.g.
>   cp33d would be the CPython 3.3 ABI with debugging.

So `none` in this case means the package is advertised as "pure-python" (none of it's local dependencies require a specific application binary interface).

This is assuming the provided wheel files are names using [the official wheel file name convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention):

> The wheel filename is {distribution}-{version}(-{build tag})?-{python tag}-{abi tag}-{platform tag}.whl.
>
> **distribution**
>
> Distribution name, e.g. 'django', 'pyramid'.
>
> **version**
>
> Distribution version, e.g. 1.0.
>
> **build tag**
>
> Optional build number. Must start with a digit. A tie breaker if two wheels have the same version. Sort as the empty string if unspecified, else sort the initial digits as a number, and the remainder lexicographically.
>
> **language implementation and version tag**
>
> E.g. 'py27', 'py2', 'py3'.
>
> **abi tag**
>
> E.g.
>   'cp33m', 'abi3', 'none'.
>
> **platform tag**
>
> E.g. 'linux_x86_64', 'any'.