# Python wheel force ABI to "none"

Tags: python, python-wheel

I would think this is an easy question, but I haven't found an answer yet, so I'm posting here.

I have a Python 3 app, that I package into a platform wheel. I have the setup.py and everything works as expected. The only thing I can't figure out is the generated wheel always includes an ABI tag (like"cp34m"), and when that's included I find that I can't actually install the wheel via pip. (My build script installs the latest pip, setuptools, and wheel before running.)

The solution is simple. I just change the file name of the wheel to change "cp34m" to "none". This is obviously easy to add into my build script, but I wonder if it's possible to set an option for bdist_wheel or something so that the .whl file that's generated has none set on its own?

The command I use to create the wheel is (for example on x64):

`python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win_amd64`

That creates a wheel like:

`mpf_mc-0.30.0.dev269-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`

Which I then rename before uploading to PyPI to:

`mpf_mc-0.30.0.dev269-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`

Everything seems to work fine by manually renaming it. But I wonder if this the right way to do it, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same question and I'm puzzled by this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005870/christoph-gohlke-naming-convention-for-unofficial-windows-binaries-for-python-ex?rq=1 didn't enlight me either.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer without seeing your `setup.py` file, but I will give my thought:

- the naming of the wheel postfix is a combination of the python tag, ABI tag, and platform tag, [as shown here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#overview). But it sounds like you already knew that.

  - [This link explaining it all](https://snarky.ca/the-challenges-in-designing-a-library-for-pep-425/) is less official, but clearer, and [here is the definition of ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).
    In my ignorant understanding, the ABI is the service level agreement (interface) between applications.
  - For the purposes of Python, the ABI is *often the same as the python tag*, with some additional info like the `m` you have in your case, which means the [Cython aspects of it used `malloc`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-pymalloc.html).

---

### Reason Your Solution Works

So, I would guess the reason things *do not work* when you use the original name and do work once you change the name is:

1. `pip` will not let you install things using the `m` part of the ABI tag... *probably* because it has not been vetted, and not because of any real problem, and/or
2. you are not *actually* using any aspects of Cython that depend upon `malloc`.

---

### Reason The ABI Tag Is Being Added

Now, if we assume that there is no real need for the `m` tag, as I said, then the reason it is probably being added is that you have a dependency in your setup file that needs it.

I am primarily a data scientist, so I will use a common example from there: `numpy` is compiled down to C code and has many Python calls to that lower level language to boost speed. Even if I write pure Python 3 code, *and do not even use `numpy` anywhere*, if I have a dependency in my setup file that asks for `numpy`, then I will have a platform-specific build. However, more common is that I am in fact using `numpy`, but I may not be using any aspects of it that rely upon C. (in `numpy`, that is rare, as all array initializations happen in C, but I hope you get the idea.)  I do not know what forces ABI-specific builds, but I would guess you have some dependency asking for it, but which is never really used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something has changed since you posted your question - I just tried your command to create a wheel file on my own project:

```
~$ python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name win_amd64
```

and the result file is:

```
my_project-1.0.0-py2-none-win_amd64.whl
```